# Navigation Drawer not showing when I hide ADS

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, navigation-drawer

I have an android app with a navigation drawer (Sidebar) and ads on the main activity xml layout. I have a broadcast receiver inside of the Activity that listens for changes in internet connectivity. If the internet connection is good then I make the adView visible, but if the internet connection fails, I change the visibility of the adView to GONE.

The problem is when I change the visibility of the adView to GONE then the navigation drawer won't open for some odd reason. Only when I close the navigation drawer with the visibility of the adView set to GONE can I catch a quick glimpse of it closing... but when I open it I cannot see that it is opened. It appears that it has opened, but that it is not visible. If I turn my wifi back on, the adView shows and the problem doesn't exist anymore. It would be nice if I could make the ADS disappear completely if the wifi or data connection turned off.

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.packagename"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<RelativeLayout 
android:id = "@+id/activity_relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_above = "@+id/adView"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                     android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                     android:background="@color/Blue"
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxx-xx-xxxx"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    android:background="@color/LightGrey"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```